# Check If Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer can Resolve

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

Is there a way in Castle Windsor to see if the IContainer can resolve All Instances.

I have a class in my Nunit Test DLL. What I would like to do is test to see if the `IWindsorContainer` can resolve all Registered Installers.

if not then the Test case for the resolver should fail.

the class I have at the moment is

```
    using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
    using Castle.Windsor;
    using NUnit.Framework;
    using System;

    namespace UnitTest
    {
        public class IOCBaseTest<T> : IDisposable
        {
            protected IWindsorContainer _container;

            public IOCBaseTest()
            {
                _container = new WindsorContainer();

                _container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("IOC").InNamespace("IOC.Installers.Business", false));
                _container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("UnitTest.Moq"));
            }

            [TestCase]
            public void TestWetherIOCContainerIsCorrectlySetup()
            {
var _handler = _container.Kernel.GetHandler(typeof(T)).CurrentState;

            Assert.AreEqual(_handler, Castle.MicroKernel.HandlerState.Valid);
            }
            [TestFixtureSetUp()]
            public abstract void SetupTests();

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _container.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that when I debug the `IWindsorContainer` I can see if there is potentially misconfigured resolvers. But how do I access this? or is there a way to test if the `_container` has any issues.

Edit: I Think I may have found the Issue, but need to test more... 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. Windsor has diagnostics subsystem for this very purpose. [The documentation has all the details.](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/debugger-views.md#access-debugger-information-from-code)

Also, I'd recommend encapsulating your registration code in [installers](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/installers.md).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I didn't know about it at all. 

I have all my installers broken out in the IOC namespace. Do I need to register them in the way I have done so? or will they be registered automatically? Sorry I am new to IOC.